# time data does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, timestamp

I got this code but i keep getting this error:

```
time data "'2019-05-23 11:42:35'" does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
```

Can someone help me.

```
df_conv['conversation_raw'].loc[3]
'2019-05-23 11:41:59', '2019-05-23 11:38:57', '2019-05-23 11:31:16'

f = datetime.strptime(df_conv['conversation_raw'].loc[3], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')

error: time data "'2019-05-23 11:42:35'" does not match format '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
```

Comment: In your first statement you are using `loc[3]` but in the second statement you use `loc[0]`. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: @KurtKline It was a mistake, fixed now

Comment: It appears that the time `str` you're feeding to `strptime` (literally) contains the enclosing single quotes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the single quotes (`'`) characters from your datetime string (`"'2019-05-23 11:42:35'"`).

Try:

```
f = datetime.strptime(df_conv['conversation_raw'].loc[0].replace("'",""), '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

For multiple datetime strings, try:

```
f = [datetime.strptime(x.replace("'",""),'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') for x in df_conv['conversation_raw'].loc[0].split(", ")]
```

Comment: It works for when there is only one date, but when there are more than one I get: 'unconverted data remains: "dates after first" '

Answer (score 1):

Use the built-in `to_datetime` - it parses the strings correctly, even though there are additional quotes:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.to_datetime("'2019-05-23 11:42:35'")

Out[1]: Timestamp('2019-05-23 11:42:35')
```

Answer (score 1):

I used the infer_datetime_format=True so Pandas will automatically choose the right format for you like so:

```
        dft["Datetime"] = pd.to_datetime(dft["Datetime"],infer_datetime_format=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
f = datetime.strptime(df_conv['conversation_raw'].loc[3], "'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'")
```